# Running solr in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs, solrcloud

I could not run SolrCloud on HDFS, I tried to run many variations of the command:

```
java -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.hdfs.home=hdfs://localhost:50070/testing/data
```

---

Can anyone post a correct the command that works directly? 
Preferably if it works on a schema-less configuration.